# Wamp Server 2.4 is not going online obstinately

Tags: windows, apache, wamp, port, remote-access

I have been searching this problem about 4 hours and I got nothing in my hands.
Awkwardly, I'm a Cisco Certified Professional and nevertheless its beyond my experties.

Here is my system:

- Linksys CISCO X2000 Modem + Router Combo
- 1x Static IP Address (212.253.77.69) [Home]
- 2x LAN IP Address (192.168.1.100 [My Laptop] -- 192.168.1.104 [Bridged VirtualBox Guest Adapter])
- demo.webastian.ch [Amazon EC2] --> pointed to 212.253.77.69 [Home]

---

On My Laptop:

- I have a fresh installed "Wampserver (64 bits & PHP 5.4) 2.4"
- Windows 8 Professional 64-bit (x64)
- Windows Firewall Private/Public off state.
- Network Card: 192.168.1.100

I used Demilitarized Zone (DMZ) to route every incoming IP to 192.168.1.100 and even tried to turn off the built-in firewall of CISCO (but not even close to solution), so I don't have to open ports anymore or forward anything through my router.

When you try http://demo.webastian.ch at the moment, you will be penetrating 192.168.1.100:80 of my Local Network.

I did put online the Wamp Server by left clicking to the tray icon.

I can access my web server by:

- 127.0.0.1
- localhost
- demo.webastian.ch (I did change the hosts file of windows and set this dns record to 127.0.0.1)
- 192.168.1.100 (on my laptop and on my iphone)

But I can not reach my web server remotely. (I tried through Edge/3G and my friends computer using teamviewer.)

So I thought it was a windows related problem but it wasnt. Therefore I installed VirtualBox and Server 2003. I used the same configurations except routing the public ip to x.104

I tried modding the httpd.conf, I tried several things that I don't remember each of it (that much) but no response.

---

On VMBox (Through My Laptop):

- I have a fresh installed "Wampserver (32 bits & PHP 5.4) 2.4"
- Windows Server 2003 Enterprise R2 32-bit (x86)
- Windows Firewall off state.
- Network Card: 192.168.1.104
- .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 (had to install or wampmanager wont start)

---

I got a dead end & I'd like to hear some other thoughts.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please see this handy info on fixing some of WAMP 2.5's little hiccups.

[WAMPServer 2.5 release notes and corrections](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123685)

Your problem is that the script that executed that request ( c:\wamp\scripts\onlineOffline.php ) somehow got released in UNIX format. The above doc tells you how to fix this.

Comment: The WAMP Online/Offline thing is not working even its released under UNIX or converted to DOS. I solved the problem by myself at there. Outside of it, somehow the remote connection worked well. Thank you for the article.

Comment: The link is now dead.  Please do not make link only answer.